# Overwriting folders with git

Tags: django, git

I'm learning how to use django on a EC2 server, but i am editing the code on my local computer.  When i run things like :

```
python manage.py startapp polls
```

It creates a folder with various files inside.  Instead of individually adding the files to git, which leaves the possibility of me forgetting to add every newly created file, is it good practice just to:

```
git add (the root django project directory)
```

everytime django creates new files?

If this isn't good practice, what methods do you guys use to ensure that all files get added to git everytime new files are created?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-thinking this. Ignore files you think you should (like *.pyc). Add all the files or do them individually, whichever you prefer. If you accidentally added one you shouldn't have, do a checkout of that file so that you don't add it. If you already committed with a file, git delete the file and commit.

Answer (score 1):

You use `git status`, it will give you the list of all the files it's currently not tracking, so you can use that as a reference if you're afraid you'll forget something.

Additionally, I would say that you  don't want to forget to properly setup your *.gitignore*, and then you can instruct git to add everything, otherwise, like [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11161642/1476449) suggested, you would potentially be adding **.pyc* files, which you don't want to do.

Comment: i know the pyc files aren't useful, but other than taking up extra space on bitbucket, why else is it bad?

Comment: Having *.pyc files (essentially compiled python byte-code) in your commits doesn't bring any additional information to your project - every time you change the code, it will also change, it also slows down the processing by the version control software, and basically pollutes your repository with files that are neither necessary nor useful to you or other developers working on the project.